# How to parse the receipt for In-App purchase in iOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, receipt

I am trying to implement subscription Model in my IAP, So I read the apple docs,

Apple mentions two methods

a) Validating Locally

b) Validating using App store (We need to have our own server to do the talking)

I used the second method and wrote the code, as mentioned in the apple docs, but

**I dont have my own server,**

Here is how I parsed the receipt

```
NSData *receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL]];


                NSError *error;


                NSDictionary *requestContents = @{
                                                  @"receipt-data": [receipt base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]
                                                  };

                NSData *requestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:requestContents
                                                                      options:0
                                                                        error:&error];


                if (!requestData) { /* ... Handle error ... */ }



                //  NSError *error;
                NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"];
                NSMutableURLRequest *storeRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:storeURL];
                [storeRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
                [storeRequest setHTTPBody:requestData];

                // Make a connection to the iTunes Store on a background queue.
                NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
                [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:storeRequest queue:queue
                                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                                           if (connectionError) {
                                               /* ... Handle error ... */
                                           } else {
                                               NSError *error;
                                               NSDictionary *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];

                                               if (!jsonResponse) { /* ... Handle error ...*/ }
                                               /* ... Send a response back to the device ... */
                                           }
                                       }];
```

I got the response perfectly where I can see all the details.

But apple in the docs, mentions this " **It is not possible to build a trusted connection between a user’s device and the App Store directly because you don’t control either end of that connection."**

So I am not sure, whether I can use this code for my production.

Secondly, the first  method where apple mentions to validate the receipt locally, I want to know how to parse the receipt. They talk about some Payload which is PKCS #7 container. So how to parse this.

Regards
Ranjit

Comment: You can't say for sure, ever, that the data you receive on your device actually came from Apple, because users could intercept the message and let them be handled by another service. Besides that, please split two questions into two actual questions on the site, so people can respond specifically to one or the other.

Comment: Hello @ErikDolor, thanks for your response.Can you throw some light on second method?